# Pipe stdout to multiple processes [zsh]

Tags: pipe, zsh

I'm aware of the ability for zsh to do:

```
ls -1 >foo >bar
```

But let's say I want to run both outputs through another command. For instance, how would I combine these two commands so as to avoid running `mysqldump` twice?

```
mysqldump db1 | bzip2 > db1.sql.bz2
mysqldump db1 | mysql db2
```

The closest I can come up with is:

```
mysqldump db1 >db1.sql | mysql db2
bzip2 db1.sql
```

But I'd rather not write the file to disk uncompressed (it's big!).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following works:

```
echo abc > >(gzip > 1) > >(xz > 2)
```

Modified for your example (but untested):

```
mysqldump db1 > >(bzip2 > db1.sql.bz2) > >(mysql db2)
```

or, probably better:

```
{ mysqldump db1 } > >(bzip2 > db1.sql.bz2) > >(mysql db2)
```

// I found almost the same example in PROCESS SUBSTITUTION section in `man zshexpn`:

> Also note that the previous example can be more compactly and efficiently written (provided the MULTIOS option is set) as:
>
> ```
>    paste <(cut -f1 file1) <(cut -f3 file2) \
>    > >(process1) > >(process2)
> ```
>
> The shell uses pipes instead of FIFOs to implement the latter two process substitutions in the above example.
>
> There is an additional problem with >(process); when this is attached to an external command, the parent shell does not wait for process to finish and hence an immediately following command cannot rely on the results being complete.  The problem and solution are the same as described in the section MULTIOS in zshmisc(1).  Hence in a simplified version of the example above:
>
> ```
>    paste <(cut -f1 file1) <(cut -f3 file2) > >(process)
> ```
>
> (note that no MULTIOS are involved), process will be run asynchronously.  The workaround is:
>
> ```
>    { paste <(cut -f1 file1) <(cut -f3 file2) } > >(process)
> ```
>
> The extra processes here are spawned from the parent shell which will wait for their completion.

Answer (score 7):

You can use process substitution.

In zsh:

```
ls -1 > >(grep foo) > >(grep bar)
```

In bash:

```
ls -1 | tee >(grep foo) >(grep bar) >/dev/null
```

Process substitution manages named pipes for you.

Comment: +1 - I accepted @ZyX since it's a more complete answer - it addresses the issue with waiting for the command to complete - but I like the option here to use bash with tee, since I'm not always in zsh. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can connect processes through fifo's and use tee utility to copy the standard output to each fifo and to stdout. Something like:

```
mkfifo db1.sql
bzip2 db1.sql &
mysqldump db1 | tee db1.sql | mysql db2
```